# Italic or upgright font for circuit components

Tags: diagram

Should one italicize symbols used to represent electronic components in a circuit diagram?

Some context:

[According to NIST](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/typefaces.pdf), typefaces for symbols should be italic if they represent a quantity or variable. The problem I see is that sometimes this is the case and sometimes it isn't.

For example, a resistor could be represented as "R1" and represents a quantity, namely the resistance of that particular resistor and hence, it should be italicized. In an accompanying text you could write "R1 = 1 kOhm" However, a transistor could be represented as Q1, but does not represent a single quantity, but rather the type of component used or multiple quantities. The quantities associated with it could be printed alongside it, such as "W/L = 360/2000 nm" in case of a MOSFET or "Beta = 400 in case of a BJT". Hence, I feel that it shouldn't be italicized, since you wouldn't write "M1 = 360/2000 nm". But I also feel that it is inconsistent to italicize some types of components and not other types.

So in summary, I can think of 3 ways to do it: (feel free to suggest other ways)

1. Italicize everything -- Problem: "wrong" style for transistors
2. Italicize nothing -- Problem: "wrong" style for resistors
3. Only italicize the components that can be represented by a single quantity -- Problem: inconsistent style between components

So which is the "correct" way to do it for example in scientific publications? (or in any situation)

Comment: Someone is thinking too hard I reckon. Nobody would write "R1 = 1 kohm" on a schematic, you would just have "R1" and "1k" (or maybe "1k0" or "1.0k"). "R1" in the accompanying bill of materials would give the part number for the resistor and that part number would embody the value.

Comment: R1, R2, R3, R4 .... Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 are reference designators. The number digit part of the designators has nothing to do with the number of components in the design nor does it have anything to do with the value of the component. It is common to see designators like R16J4 which may be the 4th resistor found in the 16J matrix position of the board. See...no applicability to quantity of resistors. Like Andy says....you are thinking way to hard in this matter and confusing yourself in the process.

Comment: You *will* get criticised for illegible, upside down or sideways, too small, dirty/broken or incorrect information on a circuit diagram. You won't get criticised for handwritten (as long as it's clear) or any legible font (with the possible exception of Comic Sans, but that's for other reasons!) If your scientific publication is a journal, ask the editor what their house rules are, before you get too far down the path of schematic preparation. Sizes of blocks, use of intrapage connectors and busses, ordering of designators, symbol conventions, have a far bigger impact on look and readability

Comment: That NIST document is for text. If you refer to parts of the schematic in the text, then you should follow those rules. Look to see if they have a separate document that addresses the annotation of schematics, which are a special sub-class of drawing.

Comment: @Andy aka: What I meant was, you can write "R1 = 1kOhm" in an accompanying text... or maybe more likely "fc1 = 1/(2*pi*R1*C1)".

Comment: @Michael Karas: If you have a simple schematic that you use for teaching someone something about a circuit I can imagine writing things in an accompanying text such as "For example, if R1 = 1kOhm...".

Comment: @Neil_UK: Yes, I will be criticized for all of that. I don't think that it is a reason to be sloppy in other areas though, but yeah, as others have said, I might be thinking too hard.

Comment: @nijoakim your opening sentence specifically mentions a "schematic diagram" and there is absolutely no-need to write "R1 = 1kOhm". Nobody will do it, no problem needs fixing.

Comment: @Andyaka You are correct. However, a few sentences down I also mention that someone could want to write "R1 = 1 kOhm" in an accompanying text; That is, not in the actual schematic diagram. I guess I could have been more clear. I now changed it to circuit diagram, as that might be less confusing for what is the intent of the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules, ISO 31-13:1992 apply to scientific papers, journals, datasheets and books.

"Schematic or Logic or circuit " diagrams detailed rules , and other document types used in electrotechnology, are provided in the international standard IEC 61082-1:2015 and do not use the same rules.

Learning to adopt standards makes documents look more professional and readable by others, but there are many styles and many existing standards for different document content types.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem is, that document costs more than £200 / $200 to obtain if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: typical for all standards and there are a lot of them, IPC, IEC, ISO

Comment: Personally, I like Tektronix's schematic corporate standards